# Call Elastic Job from a Runbook in the Automation account

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a database in Azure SQL called DatabaseA - NOTE - not a managed instance and not SQL on a virutal machine.

DatabaseA has an elastic job agent associated with it and it calls ElasticJobA and it is scheduled to run nightly and it works.

ElasticJobA is called from T-SQL in Azure SQL via the built-in scheduling that is in the jobs tables.  ElasticJobA executes a series of steps to create Fact tables which I use as a source for an SSAS tabular database named SSASTabularCubeB.

I use Runbooks to process the SSAS tabular database and that works fine.  It is scheduled to run after the Elastic job complete but is not dependant on it.  This means that if my Elastic job fails on DatabaseA,  SSASTabularDatabaseB still runs which causes problems.

To stop this happening, I want to call the Elastic Job from the same Runbook Script that processes the tabular database.  If I could do that, I could have it stop (i.e. not run the SSASTabularDatabaseB unless the ElasticJobA completes successfully).  So if ElasticJobA failed, it would not try to process SSASTabularDatabaseB.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The Runbook script I am using to process SSASTabularDatabaseB looks like this:

```
$_Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "ServicePrincipal"

Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName "SSASTabularDatabaseB" 
                            -RefreshType "Full" 
                            -Server "asazure://uksouth.asazure.windows.net/MyServer" 
                            -ServicePrincipal -Credential $_Credential
```

I know there are probably other ways to do this but please do not suggest I move to a managed instance or full SQL on a VM in Azure.  We have a requirement to use Azure SQL.

Any help given much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the steps provided in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-powershell-create#run-the-job) Azure document fits your case, then I believe you may execute the job using PowerShell cmdlet [Start-AzSqlElasticJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/start-azsqlelasticjob?view=azps-7.1.0) which also returns a job execution id that can be polled to view it's status. Then, based on the status you may process SSAS tabular database.

If the above approach doesn't fit your use case then to execute the job using T-SQL from the runbook, see if you can import the SqlServer PowerShell module to your Azure Automation account modules and then have a runbook to execute the job as a SQL query using [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) PowerShell cmdlet or using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter, System.Data.DataSet type PowerShell objects. Then, based on the status you may process SSAS tabular database.